# What is wrong with my MySQLdb module for python?

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I have installed MySQL for python, but am not quite sure if it worked. I went on python and typed:

```
import MySQLdb
```

and the error displayed was:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.9-     intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-  macosx-10.9-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.9-  intel.egg/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I do not know what the actual error is let alone how to fix it. Do you suggest i re install it, if so, what exactly shall i do ?

I basically just need the module to work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: At the end of the error there is: `...  intel.egg/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture`. Maybe you installed MySQLdb for 32bit system vs 64bit? Or a build for a different os version which is not compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some similar trouble with python MySQLdb and _mysql modules

I re-installed them, but not with pip or easy_install I ran:

Debian Kernel (Kali, Ubuntu, Mint)

```
apt-get install python-mysql*
```

Redhat kerneal (Redhat, centOS, Fedora)

```
yum install python-mysql*
```

Hope this helps.